# without permission other schengen country travel

Tags: visas

I applied long term residency permit in spain.My papers are passed but I have no residency card because I have applies for new card.i want to vist germany.i want to know wether i have to take permission from ministry for travell in germany or i will travell on my passed papers.

Comment: Which "papers" are you talking about? Do you currently have a valid visa for Spain or for the Schengen area?

Comment: Is there a title or name on these papers? Also, do you have a passport or other id from your country of citizenship, and what country is that?

Comment: Are you talking about an expired residence permit?

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't very clear but I think it's nonetheless possible to give an answer.

You can, as you probably know, travel to Germany on foot of a Schengen visa, a Spanish visa or a Spanish residence permit. On the other hand, if you are tolerated in Spain on the basis of a pending application for your first residence permit but your visa already expired, you are almost certainly not allowed to travel to Germany.

If you had a residence permit but it expired (and you still have the card itself), you have applied for a renewal and have some documentation to that effect, you might be allowed to travel to Germany, I am not sure. In that case, it would also probably depend on your exact status/the nature of the document you have.

You also need a valid passport in any case.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why all this trouble is necessary if he's already in the Schengen area and it's a short trip, there's no checks between Spain and Germany

Comment: @blackbird57 How do you mean that? Why the OP should worry about the rules? Why the rules are that way?

Comment: Maybe I still don't understand the OP's question, but I mean if he has status in Spain why is it a problem to travel to Germany ?

Comment: @blackbird57 The Schengen system is a bit more complex than it might seem at first. Schengen countries do recognize many visas and residence permits from other Schengen countries… but not all. There are in fact some very specific situations in which you have a right to stay in a Schengen country but not to go to another one. Regular travellers/expats would not usually end up in such a situation but they do exist.

Comment: Typically, it's the case for asylum *seekers* (i.e. before a decision has been made) and people on temporary residence permits (e.g. you find yourself staying illegally or with an expiring visa but you have some claim to a residence permit and are allowed to stay as long as your application is pending).

Comment: @blackbird57 Even for a relatively simple case like a residence card for EU citizen family, bureaucratic delays can create a gap of several months between the end of the visa and the moment you have a document proving your new status (see http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/7010/rights-for-spouses-of-eu-citizens-french-residence-permit-in-a-timely-manner).

Comment: Wow, learn something new every day...

Comment: @blackbird57 the other way if looking at this is that there is an excellent chance, owing to the lack of border controls, that the trip to Germany would not involve an encounter with German immigration authorities.  But there is also a chance that the traveler would be subjected to random inspection.  The consequences of that inspection could be severe.